# Removing light switch but keeping the power

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I have a three switch outlet on my living room wall. the leftmost switch was to a can light above the mantel, the middle to the fan portion of the fan and the right to the light portion of the fan. Upon moving into my home I have replaced the fan with a newer one that makes the need for a light switch unneccessary and i have removed the can light. I mounted my tv above the mantel and used the power from the can light to make the outlet behind the TV. Now if I turn the switch off it turns my TV off.

I have a single story home with a attic over everything but the builder ran all the wiring through the walls for the outlets and for the lights he ran them in the attic. I want to keep the power to the tv and i'd like to run recessed lighting off of one of the switches that i first mentioned. help please

Comment: Do you know if the unswitched power from your breaker/fuse goes to the ceiling fixtures first, or to the switches first? I'm assuming if they're all on the same circuit it goes to the switches, but it would be helpful to know for certain.

Comment: the unswitched power goes first to the switches and then to the light. All of the outlets and lights in the living room are on the same breaker switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the TV. Simply use a twist-on wire connector to pertinently connect the two wires together, instead of connecting them to the switch.

As for adding more lights.  If you have attic access, you'll simply install all the lights, and run the wiring from the attic. Run a line from the switch box to the first light, and connect all the other lights in parallel with the first one.  If you're not sure how to wire a simple light circuit, I suggest studying up or hiring a professional.

Comment: That was my idea in a nutshell (and yes i have attic access to the whole area) the issue i have is that i have one wire running out of the breaker to the top of the wall, then two wires running out of the wall from the switch. So are you saying to tap into the wire running into the wall for the TV power? If thats the case then it makes the issue of the recessed lighting fix itself like you stated

Comment: You said the receptacle for the TV is currently controlled by a switch, is that true?  If so, you can just pull the switch out of the box, remove the wires from it, and connect the wires together (not including the ground wire).  Then instead of putting the switch back in the box, just cover it with a blank cover.  Then the TV receptacle will always be on.

Comment: I've thought of that but i was wanting to use that switch and existing wiring for a recessed lighting project so I don't have to fish wires, then just add a dimmer switch where the switch is now. I'd like to find a way to bypass the switch completely while retaining power to the switch so i can use its function later.